# Need help to solve the issue in windows tester pro for eclipse 4

Tags: junit4, rcp, e4

I am getting following error when running windows tester pro in e4 application.
could anyone help me in solve the issue

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/baseadaptor/loader/BaseClassLoader
    at com.windowtester.internal.runtime.bundle.BundleResolver.bundleForClass(BundleResolver.java:18)
    at com.windowtester.internal.runtime.bundle.BundleResolver.bundleNameForClass(BundleResolver.java:30)
    at com.windowtester.internal.runtime.bundle.BundleClassReference.forBundleClass(BundleClassReference.java:25)
    at com.windowtester.internal.runtime.ClassReference.forBundleClass(ClassReference.java:16)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.WidgetLocator.<init>(WidgetLocator.java:76)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.WidgetLocator.<init>(WidgetLocator.java:105)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.locator.SWTWidgetLocator.<init>(SWTWidgetLocator.java:159)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.locator.MenuItemLocator.<init>(MenuItemLocator.java:65)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.locator.MenuItemLocator.<init>(MenuItemLocator.java:56)
    at com.bosch.bdxeditor.abstracts.AbstractTestAction.loadBDXFiles(AbstractTestAction.java:39)
    at com.bosch.bdxeditor.action.BackwardactionTest.testBackwardAction(BackwardactionTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.common.UITestCaseCommon.access$0(UITestCaseCommon.java:1)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.common.UITestCaseCommon$2.run(UITestCaseCommon.java:130)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.common.UITestCaseCommon$3.run(UITestCaseCommon.java:151)
    at com.windowtester.internal.runtime.junit.core.SequenceRunner$1.run(SequenceRunner.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.BaseClassLoader cannot be found by com.windowtester.runtime_6.0.0.r36x201009131510
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing `org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.BaseClassLoader` class is not part of Eclipse 4 so this code will only run in Eclipse 3.

Comment: Shall how to run windows tester pro in E4?

Comment: You can't - unless you can find an updated version somewhere.